# Replacing input with div, after replacing div with input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I replace a div with a text input so the user can edit the text. When the user hits enter, I want the text input to change back into a div with the edited text.

The problem I'm having I can't get the text input to change back into a div after pressing enter. I've tried `replaceWith()` and a number of combinations of JQuery functions that should do this, but I can't figure it out. Can anyone help?

Here is the div containing the comment text to be edited

```
<div id="comment-message-' + comment.id + '">' + comment_message + '</div>
```

The user clicks a link to edit the comment and the comment turns into a text input. This works fine

```
<a href="javascript:editComment(' + comment.id + ');">Edit Comment</a>
```

This is the function that changes the comment into a text input. This works

```
function editComment(id) {
    var t = $('#comment-message-' + id).text();
    $('#comment-message-' + id).replaceWith('<form id="edit-comment-form-' + id + '" name="edit-comment-form-' + id + '" action="javascript:callAPI(' + id + ')"><input id="edit-comment-' + id + '" name="edit-comment-' + id + '" type="text" value="' + t + '"/></form>');
}
```

Using the Facebook API, I make the call. If there is no error, the text input changes into a div with the new comment. The API call here works, but the change from text input to div does not

```
function callAPI(id) {
    var e = document.getElementById('edit-comment-' + id).value,
        edit = { message: e };

    FB.api('/' + id, 'POST', edit, function (response) {
        if (response && !response.error) {
            var comment = $('#comment-message-' + id),
                form = $('#edit-comment-form-' + id); // forgot to add '#' here 
            comment.removeChild(form);
            comment.html('<div id="comment-message-' + id + '">' + e + '</div>');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You should probably use contenteditable for this. That way, you can just add and remove the contenteditable attribute to change modes.

Comment: @firefoxuser_1 Thanks for the idea. Unfortunately, `contenteditable` doesn't give the user explicit direction telling them they can edit the text, which I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use below code to replace input type to div

```
FB.api('/' + id, 'POST', edit, function (response) {
    if (response && !response.error) {
        $('#edit-comment-form-' + id).replaceWith('<div id="comment-message-' + id + '">' + e + '</div>')
    }
});
```

you alrady replace $('#comment-message-' + id) with input form so do same you need to replace $('#edit-comment-form-' + id) to  $('#comment-message-' + id)

Comment: Damn I tried that last night, must have had a typo in there somewhere though. Thanks, it works!